# Oracle query to getting average for each 5 Min

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I Have Table Like there

### Table

DAY       LABEL                VALUE1

- 07-17-2014  08:19:39  40.2
- 07-17-2014  08:19:49  42.2
- 07-17-2014 08:19:59   37.1
- 07-17-2014 11:25:51   51.8
- 07-17-2014 11:26:01     52.1
- 07-17-2014 11:26:11 51.8
- 07-17-2014 11:26:21 44.1
- 07-17-2014 11:26:31 41.3
- 07-17-2014 11:26:51 59.1

i want oracle query to diasplay table one minute or 5 minute taking seconds as average

### Example

07-17-2014  08:19    41.3

07-17-2014  11:25    51.8

07-17-2014  11:26   52.7

07-17-2014  11:27   ......

Comment: It's not clear what you'd do if you also had the values 08:18:20. How do you "take seconds as average"?

Comment: It would help if you formatted your table and results as a code block; used consistent data between the table and example result; and showed how you get from one to the other. How would do you do it on paper? You also talk about both 1-minute and 5-minute grouping but your result is (I think) only 1-minute. If you do want 5-minute too you'd need to explain how each period is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding a date to minutes is easy, just use

```
trunc(day_label, 'MI')
```

To compute the average of column value1, you'll need to group by this trunc-value like so:

```
SELECT trunc(day_label, 'MI') AS m, round(avg(value1),1) as avg_secs
  FROM t
 GROUP BY trunc(day_label, 'MI')
 ORDER BY trunc(day_label, 'MI');

17.07.2014 08:19:00 39,8 
17.07.2014 11:25:00 51,8
17.07.2014 11:26:00 49,7
```

Comment: this is my actual query ( select type,concat(day,TIMSTAMP_DAY) label,ENTC_PERCENT value1  from  sample_table WHERE HOSTNAME='ABCDEF' order by 2 desc ) can u give solution for this..

Comment: I need more details for that: 1. What datatype are `day` and `timestamp_day`? 2. What's type, average over that as well? 3. is `etc_percent` a percent value? Does it make sense to average over percent, mathematically speaking?